# Retornar uma parte do codigo em python

Tags: python, if, while

Opa, tudo bem? Minha duvida basicamente é em como eu posso fazer o codigo voltar a escolha do usuario após o cadastro ja ter sido feito, ou ja ter executado tudo que eu queria. Pois, após eu escolher a opção desejada e fazer todo o cadastro, o código para, e gostaria que ele continuasse para escolher a opção novamente!
Obrigado

```
arquivo_clientes = 'cadastro_clientes.txt'
arquivo_motos = 'cadastro_motos.txt'
arquivo_vendas = 'cadastro_vendas'

print('Bem vindo a concessionaria de motos GomesEnterprises, o que deseja fazer?\n')

print('1- Cadastrar um cliente\n'
  '2- Cadastrar uma moto\n'
  '3- Alterar dados de um cliente\n'
  '4- Alterar dados de uma moto\n'
  '5- Excluir um cliente\n'
  '6- Excluir uma moto\n'
  '7- Consultar Cadastro de motos\n'
  '8- Consultar Cadastro de clientes\n' )

   choose = int(input('Escolha uma opção: '))




  if choose == 1:
  cadastro_cl = open('cadastro_clientes.txt', 'a')
  nome_cl = input('Digite o nome do cliente a ser cadastrado: ')
  cadastro_cl.write(nome_cl + "\n")
  print('Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!')
  cadastro_cl.close()

  if choose == 2:
  cadastro_mt = open('cadastro_motos.txt', 'a')
  nome_mt = input('Digite o nome da moto a ser cadastrada: ')
  cadastro_mt.write(nome_mt + "\n")
  print('Motocicleta cadastrada com sucesso!')
  cadastro_mt.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque todo o seu código em um loop e permita que o usuário interrompa selecionando alguma opção. Por exemplo:

```py
arquivo_clientes = 'cadastro_clientes.txt'
arquivo_motos = 'cadastro_motos.txt'
arquivo_vendas = 'cadastro_vendas'

executar_codigo = True

while executar_codigo:
    print('Bem vindo a concessionaria de motos GomesEnterprises, o que deseja fazer?\n')
    
    
    print('1- Cadastrar um cliente\n'
      '2- Cadastrar uma moto\n'
      '3- Alterar dados de um cliente\n'
      '4- Alterar dados de uma moto\n'
      '5- Excluir um cliente\n'
      '6- Excluir uma moto\n'
      '7- Consultar Cadastro de motos\n'
      '8- Consultar Cadastro de clientes\n'
      '9- Sair\n')
    
    choose = int(input('Escolha uma opção: '))
    
    
    if choose == 1:
      cadastro_cl = open('cadastro_clientes.txt', 'a')
      nome_cl = input('Digite o nome do cliente a ser cadastrado: ')
      cadastro_cl.write(nome_cl + "\n")
      print('Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!')
      cadastro_cl.close()
    
    if choose == 2:
      cadastro_mt = open('cadastro_motos.txt', 'a')
      nome_mt = input('Digite o nome da moto a ser cadastrada: ')
      cadastro_mt.write(nome_mt + "\n")
      print('Motocicleta cadastrada com sucesso!')
      cadastro_mt.close()
    
    if choose == 9:
        # Interromper aplicação
        executar_codigo = False
```

Comment: Dá para encurtar escrevendo simplesmente `while input() != '9':`.